# How should a variable be passed within format() in Python?

Tags: python

I am seeking to be able to use variables within the format() parentheses, in order to parameterize it within a function. Providing an example below:

```
sample_str = 'sample_str_{nvars}'
nvars_test = 'apple'
sample_str.format(nvars = nvars_test)  #Successful Result: ''sample_str_apple''
```

But the following does not work -

```
sample_str = 'sample_str_{nvars}'
nvars_test_2 = 'nvars = apple'
sample_str.format(nvars_test_2) # KeyError: 'nvars'
```

Would anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: try: `{0}`. As your add dictionary in first example, it works. In second example, you add list, so you need to put position

Comment: I wanted to mention the popular advice ["keep data out of your variable names"](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html), but actually, this is more like "keep variable names out of your data"!  In any case, variable names and data live in orthogonal dimensions, it's best to try not to mix them up too much.

Comment: @wim This isn't any worse than defining a function with documented parameter names.

Comment: Don't answer your question in the question itself. Either post a proper answer, or delete the question.

Comment: @chepner - Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @chepner Yes it is.  The line `nvars_test_2 = 'nvars = apple'` has a variable name (`nvars`) hidden in a string of data (the object `'nvars = apple'`).

Comment: @wim Yes, the second approach is clearly wrong; I though you meant putting `nvars` in `sample_str` in the first place.

Comment: @wim I tend to agree but I could see the use case here - something like `"{0} hello world! {1} {2} foo bar {3} {4} {2} {0}".format(...)` could definitely benefit from named placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for guidance. I did a bit more searching. For anyone who may run into the same problem, please see examples here:  https://pyformat.info

```
sample_str = 'sample_str_{nvars}'
nvars_test_2 = {'nvars':'apple'} 
sample_str.format(**nvars_test_2)  #Successful Result: ''sample_str_apple''
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend checking out the [string format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples) examples.

Your first example works as expected.  From the documentation, you are permitted to actually name the thing you are passing into `{}`, and then pass in a same-named variable for `str.format()`:

```
'Coordinates: {latitude}, {longitude}'.format(latitude='37.24N', longitude='-115.81W')
# returns 'Coordinates: 37.24N, -115.81W'
```

Your second example doesn't work because you are not passing a variable called `nvars` in with `str.format()` - you are passing in a string: `'nvars = apple'`.

```
sample_str = 'sample_str_{nvars}'
nvars_test_2 = 'nvars = apple'
sample_str.format(nvars_test_2) # KeyError: 'nvars'
```

It's a little more common (I think) to not name those curly-braced parameters - easier to read at least.

`print('sample_str_{}'.format("apple"))` should return `'sample_str_apple'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3.6 you also have access to Python's formatted string literals.

```
>>> greeting = 'hello'
>>> name = 'Jane'
>>> f'{greeting} {name}'
'hello Jane'
```

Note that the literal expects the variables to be already present. Otherwise you get an error.

```
>>> f'the time is now {time}'
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```